# Is there a way in Magento to store/manage frontend user authentification outside ? (LDAP,etc.)

Tags: php, magento

I'm working on a multi-site project (half of them are Magento stores), and I'd like to have only one entry point for all the users, transparent for the user, everything in the same system/database for all the sites.

I'd like to know if there's alternatives to the core user authentification ? I saw that there's LDAP plugins, but only for the backend access. Is there anything for the frontend authentification ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to do it. Magento comes with an easy way to overclass the core. So it's possible to overwrite customer controller and to by-pass the Magento authentication. But you need to track everything related with subscription, password changes, etc. to overwrite those methods and link them to the LDAP

Comment: If you were successful, can you please share the code changes?